# what is this old Stackpole part?

Tags: components

Cleaning out some OLD (30-40 years) parts drawers, I came across a few of these parts:

- 14-pin DIP
- package is 3 layers, black layer in between 2 white layers (ceramic ?)
- marking says "STACKPOLE 14-13-1-R  1K" and "7711" perpendicular to that

Nothing useful googlable. Doesn't really matter - I'm just curious.   I vaguely remember it's integrated resistors of some kind.

Answer (score 6):

Sounds like a bussed resistor network, 13 1kohm resistors.

Comment: Manufactured in week 11 of 1977.

Comment: Common terminal on pin 14, 13 independent terminals on pins 1-13 ?

Comment: Maybe. Easy enough to suss out with a DMM, just look for the 1k resistors.